# How to print day of the date in java without using inbuilt calendar packages api's

Tags: java

in this program i got all ordinary years day approximately.. 
example by giving input 1 1 2014 i get output as wednesday..
but not on leap year example by giving input 1 1 2000 i'm get exact answer saturday..
but i get answer for 1 1 2000 is monday.. can anyone solve this...

[Reference for Day of the date](http://easycalculation.com/funny/shortcuts/day.php)

```
//reference i made this program: http://easycalculation.com/funny/shortcuts/day.php
//gd = given date
//gm = given month
//gy = given year
//ym = year modulus (year % 100 to get last two digits)
//yp = year process (ym%4 to get remainder)
//wd = week days (0 for sunday, 1 for monday and so on...)
//d = day calculation (to get remainder from 0 to 6 .. which represents wd[0]
//for sunday so on)

import java.util.Scanner;
class dayof
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    int gd,gm,gy,ym,yp,d;
    int[] m=new int[]{0,3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5};
    String[] wd=new String[]{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date Month Year \"DD MM YYYY\"");
    gd=ip.nextInt();
    gm=ip.nextInt();
    gy=ip.nextInt();
    ym=gy%100;
    yp=ym%4;
    d=(gd+m[gm-1]+ym+yp+1)%7;
    System.out.print(wd[d]);
    }
}
```

Comment: huh ?? i am kinda lost.. solve what ? please reformat your questions as its hard to understand

Comment: Judging by the profile activity, he is asking us to solve his homework again.

Comment: I question the underlying algorithm

Comment: Seems to me the page you based this off of is stuck in the 20th century. Their calculation method doesn't seem to work for 2000 and later. Note their example is 1986??

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to print day of date.

try this:

```
int day=ip.nextInt();
int month=ip.nextInt();
int year=ip.nextInt();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, day);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

`Date(year,month,day)` is now deprecated. You can try [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

or you should try:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").parse(input);
String day = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(date);
```

for other format [see Java Date Format Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

[image: Formats for datetime]

Comment: While this might be a correct answer, this doesn't help OP understanding his error. It might be a homework and he might be not allowed to use `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously recommend you use better variable names; it's really hard to tell what's what.  But the answer to your question is that your array called `m` doesn't take account of leap years.  You need one such array for non-leap years and a different array for leap years.

Comment: This array m is not about measuring month lengths. The leap year rule can instead be taken care of by an additional year-related term in the formula `d=(gd+m[gm-1]+ym+yp+1)%7;`. Anyway, I don't trust his whole algorithm at all.

Comment: I understand what the array `m` is about, Meno.  It's about which day each month starts on.  That depends on the length of each month, so you need a different `m` for leap years.  The algorithm is correct if you add a check for whether the year is a leap year, and use THIS `m` if it isn't, and a different `m` if it is.  You also need to add something to handle the non-leap years where the year is divisible by 100 but not 400.  Other than those two points, the algorithm is trustworthy.

Comment: This m-array is not really related to the concrete year but only to month indices. So even if you introduce another leap-year-conscious array the whole algorithm will still miss the urgently needed information if 2000 is a leap year or not. My mathematical intuition tells me a second array only will not help. If you present such a solution as concrete code and proves its correctness then you get my upvote.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, it still wouldn't be able to deal with the case of the non-leap years that are divisible by 100.  But introducing a second `m` array will make it correct between 1 March 1900 and 28 February 2100.

Comment: You don't need a second `m`; you just need to subtract 1 if it's a leap year and the month is Jan or Feb. See my answer, for example.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").parse(input);
    String day = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your block to this... I've kept your variable names (which others have pointed out are cryptic and hard to remember), but used a more verbose name for the variable I added... This should work for any date between March 1, 1900 and Feb 29, 2100... I don't usually give answers to obvious homework, but the page you were using was a crappy algorithm, and you did have it *almost* right.

```
    int gd,gm,gy,ym,yp,d,isJanFeb;
    int[] m=new int[]{0,3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5};
    String[] wd=new String[]{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date Month Year \"DD MM YYYY\"");
    gd=ip.nextInt();
    gm=ip.nextInt();
    gy=ip.nextInt();
    ym=gy-1900;  // years since 1900
    yp=ym/4;     // leap years since 1900
    isJanFebLeap = ( gm < 3 && gy%4 == 0) ? 6 : 0;
    System.out.println(gd + " " + gm + " " + gy + " " + ym + " " + yp);
    d=(gd+m[gm-1]+ym+yp +isJanFebLeap)%7;
    System.out.print(wd[d]);
```

Your algorithm didn't take into account dates before Feb 29 in leap years (you need to subtract 1 - or add 6 mod 7 - for the leap day that's later in the year)... it also did not take into account the new century (specifically, that 1/1/1900 was not the same day of the week as 1/1/2000). You don't want `gy%100`, you want `gy-1900`.

If you want to extend it outside the 1900-2100 range, take into account the fact that century years **not** divisible by 400 are leap years. So 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 are not leap years but 2000 was.